# 3 divs same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wanna make a layout with a left menu, right menu and a middle with pages stuff just like this:
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-82HunzQsyzI/T0RaxdMxUvI/AAAAAAAAAx0/mKkTADcL_34/s1600/tc.PNG

I'm trying to do with with boostrap 4 (to help me with responsible stuff), but i can not put the 3 menus in same line

What do i doing wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      #tela {
        color: blue;
        display: inline;
        /* height:100vh; */
      }
    </style>

    <main>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container" id="tela">
      <div class="col-md-2" id="left_menu" style="background-color: green; height: 300px;">
        GREEN
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" id="middle" style="background-color: yellow; height: 300px;">
        YELLOW
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2" id="right_menu" style="background-color: red; height: 300px;">
        RED
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>


    </main>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: row within container and col within row ... follow bootstrap rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the correct Bootstrap 4 classes. Below I used:
`.d-flex` and `.flex-row` instead of `.container`
`.col` and `.col-6` for the column definitions

Hope this helps.

```css
#tela {
  color: blue;
  //display: inline;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<main>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="d-flex flex-row" id="tela">
    <div class="col" id="left_menu" style="background-color: green;">
      GREEN
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="middle" style="background-color: yellow">
      YELLOW
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="right_menu" style="background-color: red;">
      RED
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer" style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>


</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="row">` to wrap whole line might work.

Comment: Just it dont fix, but ty to help

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide your page as below, the sum of `col` classes should be 12 and inside `div` with `class="row"` to expand horizontally over the page

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"> /* left menu */ </div> 
    <div class="col-md-8"> /* middle page */ </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> /* right menu */ </div>
</div>
```

For more information check [Bootstrapb Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style type="text/css">
  #tela {
    color: blue;
    display: inline;
    /* height:100vh; */
  }
</style>

<main>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container" id="tela">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2" id="left_menu" style="background-color: green; height: 300px;">
        GREEN
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8" id="middle" style="background-color: yellow; height: 300px;">
        YELLOW
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2" id="right_menu" style="background-color: red; height: 300px;">
        RED
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer" style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>


</main>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You mean that total always have to have 12?

Comment: Yes, 2 + 8 + 2 > 12